# Magento 2 After Migration Configurable Product Price blank

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I have Migrated Magento 1.9.1.0 website in Magento 2.2.4,all data is migrated successfully.

I have an issue when checking products in admin->catalog->product and compared price with Magento 1 ,configurable products have blank price and not editable

[image]

while in Magento 1 its price is 79.95 and special price is 57.98.Variants products price are same as in Magento 1 ,please check below image

[image]

but clicking on advanced pricing,its display blank

[image]

my issue is same as below referenced but solution is not here.

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/281

I don't have idea how to resolve that issue.Special price are not display as well as config product price are displaying wrong in front-end.

Please help me if anyone have same problem.

Comment: Any update ?  i have same issue facing

Comment: @RakeshDonga,I have done this by re-importing price again.

Comment: same issue here has anybody found the solution?

Comment: Anybody found any solution ? facing same issue...